# wget mirroring website without index.html

Tags: linux, terminal, wget, mirror

I am trying to do a complete mirror of a website that has links and directories that have index pages that are not named index.html. In the html code on the live site the link just points to a directory like href=/directory. It's not dynamic because I found the html page it actually goes to when you browse to wwww.example.com/directory its just not named index.html, So when I try to brose the mirrored site offline, it doesn't direct to the correct html page, it just gives me a directory listing. 
Currently I am trying: 
    wget -nc --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"  http://example.com

Comment: You want to read about the DirectoryIndex directive in the apache configuration. Take a look at its documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: So I'm assuming there's no way I can get that from the site I'm trying to mirror; I'll just have to do it manually on my end?

Comment: Well, it is a configuration option of your http server. How would you want to "get" that from some remote site? And... _why_, since you already know what you need?

Comment: Oh, and just for the sake of completeness: the same effect can be implemented using internal rewrite rules instead of using the `DirectoryIndex` directive, but that also is usually done on the level of the http server, so nothing you can see or "get" from outside, since it is part of the internal setup.

Comment: And... for the sake of _real_ completeness: the fact that you "found the html page" does not say anything reliable about whether such file actually exists in a physical manner in the servers file system. That may as well again be a rewrite rule which triggers some internal routing script which generates the html content...

Comment: Ok, when I mirror the site, I get the html pages that I'm directed to when I click on the links on the live site, but on the mirrored site, the don't direct correctly. The pages are there, but what you are saying is that the live site has an internal http configuration that does this that a mirror can't reproduce

Comment: Sure, I understand all that. But that does not change a thing, does it? What you want does not somehow influence the way things are on the server side...

Comment: Sorry about being all over the place with this, but what you are saying is that the live site has some internal config that does this

Comment: Well, of course. I wrote about configuration directives and their use to implement certain behavior. That obviously refers to the server internal setup or configuration. Every http server has some configuration. And other things that are purely internal. The web usually is a bit more complicated that a server side file system tree hierarchy getting published via the http protocol.